# Why am I getting no nodes in touchesBegan?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I am using touchesBegan within the class of MyBall, which is an SKSpriteNode, itself, so it gets called when I click on the MyBall, and I do go past the guard line.

However, when I print the touchedNodes.count I get zero, and touchedNodes does have a raw value.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here....or missing?

p.s. I tried doing this from GameScene itself, but touchesBegan was never received.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: location)
    print ("\(touchedNodes.count)")
    
    //combine next two lines
    for node in touchedNodes.reversed(){
        var thisBall = node as? MyBall
        if thisBall!.nodeType == "ball" {
            self.currentNode = node
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I continued to search this out I realized I was chasing my own tail. Looking for touchesBegan in the wrong places, as well as having GameScene's `isUserInteractionEnabled = false`, thinking I wouldn't be touching it.

Finally I found the solution to get all touchesBegan in one place, GameScene.

So to get all touchesBegan sent to the same scene, set:
GameScene's `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`
and all other nodes to `isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Here is the Apple Developer's link that explained it all to me:

[Controlling User Interaction on Nodes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/controlling_user_interaction_on_nodes)